# what is the code for featuring data in joomla?

Tags: joomla

The following code will show in all pages, 
but I want to hide it in main page, how can I feature this?

My code

```
<div class="container-fluid bginner">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="slider-inner col-lg-3 col-xs-12 hidden-sm col-md-3">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="inner-sidebar" style="sidebar" />
       </div>
       <div class="<?php echo $main; ?>">
            <jdoc:include type="component"/>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>


<?php
    $left = $this->countModules('inner-sidebar');
        if ($left > 0)
            $main = "col-lg-9 col-xs-12 col-md-9 main-content";
        else
            $main = "col-lg-12 col-xs-12 main-content";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some solutions

[Joomla doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Giving_the_Front_Page_a_different_style_from_other_pages)